# Is there a guaranteed way to avoid padding between base and derived class?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, struct-member-alignment

I'm working on a network program that will deal with packets having a header portion and a payload portion.  The header is variable-length, with extension segments added or removed depending on network conditions.  The user data portion is a plain byte buffer, although it may be treated as some sort of structure or other during packet construction or use.

I would like to have a base class that builds & manipulates the header, with the header bytes (possibly) shifted forwards or backwards if necessary to insert an extension field, and a derived class containing the user data.  For example:

```
class hdr {
    public:
        const void *start( void ) { return uint8_t(pBuf) + sizeof(pBuf) - SIZEOF_HEADER - pExtBytes; }
    private:
        size_t   pExtBytes;
        uint32_t pBuf[16]; // header data goes here, shifted to the END of the buffer, adjacent the beginning of the derived class
        // NO PADDING HERE!
} ;

class payload1 : public hdr {
    public:
    private:
        uint8_t pData[128];
} ;

class payload2 : public hdr {
    public:
    private:
        uint16_t pData[12];
} ;
```

Is there a standard way to *guarantee* that there's no padding between `hdr` and `payload1` or `payload2`, so that I can pass `start()` to `write()` and have the header and contiguous payload transmitted out the network?  For example, if `(sizeof(hdr) % BIG_STANDARD_ALIGNMENT) == 0)` then derived classes of `hdr` will start without any extra padding?

An alternative is to use scatter/gather I/O, but that seems like a complicated setup, and I'm not sure it works to gather packet-fragments together for transmission in a single UDP packet.

Comment: there is no such way. Use a non-inherited struct with `char pBuf[]` as the last member and allocate it with corresponding sizes when needed.

Comment: IMHO, use a buffer, such as `uint8_t`, to transfer data.  Write methods that load a `class` / `struct` from the buffer.  Don't use classes or structures for direct transfer, due to padding, alignment, and vtable issues (among other possibilities).

Comment: Thanks, @Serge.  After more digging around, I think you're right: there's no language-guaranteed way to do this.  (Of course, you can get it to work with any particular compiler, and maybe with a good range of compilers, but it's not required by the spec.) . So although it pains me to include `memcpy()` in the "prepare for transmission" code path, the alternative (custom assembly?) is worse.  And CPUs are faster than networks these days anyway.

Comment: @DaveM you can use unions for array mapping.